# SQL Server stored procedure if statement injection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using SQL Server I am trying to inject a string into a SQL statement based on an if statement, note that am trying to accomplish this inside a stored procedure.

I am currently getting an error for this code:

```
Declare @topString varchar(240)

IF @topRecords > 0
SET @topString = 'top 500'
ELSE
SET @topString = ''

SELECT @topString * FROM( //incorrect syntax near FROM

SELECT  top 500 c.Id as [Customer Id],....
    UNION
    SELECT  top 500 c.Id as [Customer Id],....
)as table1 
Order by 1 desc
```

**Edit**

```
if somethingTrue
@whereCondition = '1 = 1 '
else 
@whereCondition = branch = @branch

select * from table 
where @whereCondition AND etc...
```

**Correct**

for injection inside an if statement go with Jodrell 
but if you need a dynamic top then go with what was suggested by Kaf. 
thanks both for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inject statement parts as variables like that, however you can change most values for parameters.

Having a stored procedure perform operations that may require different query plans, based on a parameter is a bad idea, the results of this SP could vary wildly based on the value of the `@topRecords` parameter. You would need to use the `RECOMPILE` option to warn the query engine, mitigating much of the benefit of SPs. Have you considered just having two stored procedures?

If you want to do it dynamically, you could build the whole statement dynamically, making one big string, then execute that.

You should investigate using `sp_executesql` to execute the `string`/`VarChar`. Then similar queries will benefit from query plan reuse.

As ever Sommarskog is a [good reference](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

---

Something like this

```
DECLARE @topString varchar(240);
DECLARE @statement varchar(max);

IF @topRecords > 0
    SET @topString = 'TOP 500';
ELSE
    SET @topString = '';

SET @statement = 'SELECT ' + @topString + ' * FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 500 c.Id as [Customer Id], ....
        UNION
        SELECT TOP 500 c.Id as [Customer Id], ....
    ) table1 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC'

/* Then execute @statement */
EXEC sp_executesql @statement
```

Comment: thank you for the help, i will most probably go with what u said but the problem is that the sql is really really big, so now i need to end an endless number of single quotes ... zzz

Comment: @rtp I can't deny its a pain. I try to do my dynamic SQL in the client, if you are using .Net it comes largely for free.

Comment: @Jodrell +1 for mind reading and answering something which did not appear on the original post.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to `decide number of top records depending on @topRecords`, you can do it using an `INT` or `BIGINT` depending on the number of records needed.

```
DECLARE @top INT --This is declared as an int here

IF @topRecords > 0
  SET @top = 500
ELSE
  SET @top = 5000000 --Make it more than records if you need all 
                              --or make it 0 if no records needed.
                              --@top has to be >=0

--How to use it
SELECT TOP (@top) * FROM YourTable
```

**EDIT:** Your question had only a top injection initially. However, If you need more injections (as per your recent question edit) then I would suggest to use a dynamic query as per `@Jordell's answer.`

Comment: +1 `Top 0` won't work though. That returns zero rows. The largest possible value that can be passed is bigint `9223372036854775807`. Could also use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get it to take account of actual value of `TOP` if that would change the plan.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, 0 is for no records. if he does not need any.

Comment: It does work but, in my testing anyway on SQL 2005. A literal value offers superior performance to a variable.

Comment: what you stated is correct but wont work if i need to inject more string, it does solve the my dynamic top problem but doesn't solve my string injection problem all together, i need to inject on the where statement to accept All or a specific condition

Comment: @rtp you should edit the question accordingly, after that edit my answer becomes more pertinent.

Comment: @Jodell OP did not say anything about `server version` or `where clauses.` I answered as per the question appeared. No fight here...lol

Comment: agreed, your answer has more utility for the orginal question. +1